# for dirs,_,files in os.walk()

Tags: python, os.walk

Can someone explain the usage of the `_` in this for loop?

```
for dirs,_,files in os.walk(directory):
   for f in files:
       yield os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirs, f))
```

My goal is to get the filenames with full path recursively. 
I got this from another question and it does exactly what I want. But I don't understand it.

Comment: `_` is just like any variable like `a` or `b` but by convention it means we don't care about it. Also, `_` will return the most recent output from a Python Interactive Session even though it wasn't stored in any variable

Comment: the [entry in the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) explained the output of `os.walk`, a 3-tuple: `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)`. so the unpacking done there is for `dirnames`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20walk#os.walk) returns the tuple `(root, dirs, files)` where

- `root`: the current directory
- `dirs`: the files in the current dir
- `files`: the files in the current dir

if you do not use one of these variables in your subsequent loop, it is customary to call it `_` (or even append a name such as `_dirs`). that way most IDEs will not complain that you have assigned a variable but you are not using it.

in your example you could do:

```
for root, _dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    pass
```

and the IDE should not complain that you are not using the variable `_dirs`.